# When giving input as 10.1 it is showing error but why?It should convert it into integer I think?

Tags: python

```
a=input()
b=int(a)
print(b)
```

I am new to programming and got an error while I have entered input as 10.1

Why is the `int(a)` function not converting `a` into an integer?

Comment: see here: int vs float: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_numbers.htm#:~:text=int%20(signed%20integers)%20%E2%88%92%20They,numbers%20with%20no%20decimal%20point.&text=float%20(floating%20point%20real%20values,the%20integer%20and%20fractional%20parts.)

Comment: You got an error, but which one? Copy'n'paste the error into the searchbar above to find similar questions. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

10.1 is not an integer, it's a float. If you want to keep the decimal you need to convert it to a float like

```
a = input()
b = float(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input()
# '10.1' because it is a string
b = float(a)
# 10.1 as string is now converted to float
c = int(b)
print(c)
# 10 is int because float is now converted to int
```

If your input was only 10, your code would have worked. If you want to handle both int and float, the example here is one way you can do it.